# How to handle multiple events on one click for multiple PictureBoxes?

Tags: vb.net

So what i want to do is to make a quiz where you choose answer with the right picture, which have to be clicked. I need 5 question, but by using Select Case method you cant directly cast Picturebox1.click

[Question with multiple picture answers which after you click will pop messagebox.show function and move on to the next question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GqpC.png)
Any help will be appreciated!!

```
 Private Sub control1_mouseclick1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox4.Click
    Dim p As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Select Case CInt(p.Tag)
        Case 1



    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I see you're casting the `sender` parameter to a PictureBox to determine which PB as clicked.  Looks good so far.  Then you're using the .Tag() property to do something.  What exactly isn't working?  Any error message?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You're already handling the `Click` event of multiple `PictureBox` controls and you're even accessing the `PictureBox` that was clicked, so anything to do with the event is completely irrelevant to your question.  If you want to now do something with the value of the `Tag` property of a `PictureBox` then that is the question that you should be asking, in which case it would be helpful to know what values the `Tag` might have and what you want to do for each one.

Comment: commenting just to get you a notification lol

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub control1_mouseclick1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox4.Click

    Select Case e
        Case 1
            If (PictureBox2.Click = True) Then
                MessageBox.Show("CORRECT!")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("INCORRECT!")

            End If
            quest2()


    End Select
End Sub
```

You right, it probably didn't make sense.. What i want to do is exactly shown in the code, but PictureBox2.Click can't be performed directly here, and I'm as beginner don't know how correctly i could do it.. The previous code i tried to use other people suggestions found on forums, but it is not clear for me how to exactly use it, so I didn't even bother myself with it. Hope you get it know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which PictureBox was clicked, you could do something like:

```
Private Sub control1_mouseclick1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox4.Click
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

    If pb Is PictureBox1 Then

    ElseIf pb Is PictureBox2 Then

    ElseIf pb Is PictureBox3 Then

    ElseIf pb Is PictureBox4 Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that make sense for me, thanks. But another problem occurred..
        Private Sub control1_mouseclick1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click, PictureBox3.Click, PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox4.Click
Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)

```
    Select Case e
        Case 1
            If pb Is PictureBox2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
                Form1.scorepoint += 1
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            End If
            question2()
        Case 2
            If pb Is PictureBox1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
                Form1.scorepoint += 1
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            End If
            question3()
        Case 3
            If pb Is PictureBox4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
                Form1.scorepoint += 1
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            End If
            question2()
        Case 4
            If pb Is PictureBox3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
                Form1.scorepoint += 1
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            End If
            question5()
        Case 5
            If pb Is PictureBox3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Correct!")
                Form1.scorepoint += 1
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            ElseIf pb Is PictureBox4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!")
            End If
    End Select
    Form1.trackscore()
End Sub
```

So when i call out select case method each   Case "number" is not declared, it shows error **"Operator '=' is not defined for types System.EventArgs.' and 'Integer'**
At the top i have 
'Dim e As Integer 'which is my Select Case variable''